# (javascript + jquery+regex)How to alert regex values when I change select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert regexp values when the selected box get changed ,
the select box have values like this

#bla:123#bla2:12345

#bla:122#bla2:12111

#bla:663#bla2:93399

I'm getting the select box value using Jquery ,here's the code I've been trying with:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#idNrel').change(function()
        {           
            var re = /#.*:(.*)#.*:(.*)/;
            var sourcestring = $('#idNrel').val();
            var results = [];
            var i = 0;
            for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {

        results[i] = matches;
        for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
        alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
        }
        i++;
    }


});
});
```

Comment: You don't need to loop. `match` should be able to extract those capturing groups into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) pointed out, there's no need for two loops as `matches` is an array of captures. Something like this should suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idNrel').change(function () {
        var self = $(this),
            r = /#[^:]+:([^#]+)#[^:]+:(.*)/g, // use global flag
            sourcestring = self.val(),
            matches = r.exec(sourcestring),
            i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i += 1) {
            // first element in the matches array will be the whole matching string
            // second element in the matches array is the first capture group
            // third element in the matches array is the second capture group
            // this pattern continues, although you have no more capture groups
            alert("Capture " + i + ": = " + matches[i]);
        }
    });
});
```

And (of course), a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4zy/

You can read up more about capture groups and JavaScript regexes here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html